# Associative array that returns function in perl

Tags: perl, hash, associative-array

Is it possible to create associative array that returns function?
Something similar to this

```
%a = ('first' => sub first { $x = @_; sprintf("(first %s)", $x); });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but you probably want `my ($x) = @_;` instead of `$x = @_;` and **drop function name** as you're dealing with anonymous function.

You can then call function as `$a{first}->([arg])`

```
my %a = ('first' => sub { my ($x) = @_; sprintf("(first %s)", $x); });
```

Comment: `$a{first}->([arg])` should be ie. `$a{first}->(3)`

Comment: I mean with this line I get compiler error `%a = ('first' => sub first { $x = @_; sprintf("(first %s)", $x); });`

Comment: You'll need to drop function name, use just `=> sub {..}`

Answer (score 5):

So close... The one detail you missed is that you're defining an anonymous sub there, so you shouldn't give it a name:

```
$ perl -E '%a = (first => sub { $x = @_; sprintf("(first %s)", $x); }); say $a{first}->(3);'
(first 1)
```

(Note that, with `$x = @_`, you're setting `$x` to the number of items in `@_`, not the first item in the array, which is why the output is "first 1" instead of "first 3".)

Answer (score 2):

You an either store a reference to an anonymous subroutine:

`my %a = ('first' => sub { my ($x) = @_; sprintf("(first %s)", $x); });`

Or a reference to a named subroutine:

```
sub first { 
  my ($x)= @_; 
  sprintf("(first %s)", $x);
}

my %a = ('first' => \&first);
```

In both cases, you dereference them the same way.

```
my @result = $a{first}->(@args);
```

This is usually called a 'dispatch table'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no associative array in perl. It is a hash
Yes you can store reference to a subroutine in a hash;

```
 my %hash=(
        'function'=>\&subroutine,
 );
 sub subroutine{
     print "hai";
 }
```

or you can create it inside the hash

Comment: perldoc perldata: Perl has three built-in data types: scalars, arrays of scalars, and associative arrays of scalars, known as "hashes".